# Django sorting queryset with nested querysets in python

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a queryset (Group) with a nested queryset (Memberships) with a nested queryset (Credits). This is the output:

```
group = [
    {
        "name": "Group2",
        "memberships": [
            {
                "username": "test1",
                "credits": [
                    {
                        "credits": 1000,
                        "year": 2020,
                        "week": 42,
                        "game_count": 1,
                        "last_game_credits": 10,
                    }
                ],
            },
            {
                "username": "test2",
                "credits": [
                    {
                        "credits": 1500,
                        "year": 2020,
                        "week": 42,
                        "game_count": 1,
                        "last_game_credits": 0,
                    }
                ],
            },
            {
                "username": "test",
                "credits": [
                    {
                        "credits": 1000,
                        "year": 2020,
                        "week": 42,
                        "game_count": 1,
                        "last_game_credits": 0,
                    }
                ],
               
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to rank the member in Memberships the following way:

credits (amount)

game_count (amount)

last_game_credits (amount)

Hence, if two players have an equal amount of credits the one with the highest game_count wins. If that is the same the one with the highest last_game_credits wins.

I want the same structure to be returned.

```
Models: 
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="memberships", 
    through='Membership')
    
class Membership(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="membership", 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
class Credits(models.Model):
    credits = models.IntegerField()
    year = models.IntegerField(default=date.today().isocalendar()[0])
    week = models.IntegerField(default=date.today().isocalendar()[1])
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="credits", 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    game_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    last_game_credits = models.IntegerField(null=True)

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    username = NameField(max_length=25, unique=True,
```

View:

```
class GroupSet(generics.ListAPIView):
    lookup_field = 'name'
    serializer_class = GroupSerializer

def get_queryset(self):

    year = self.request.query_params.get('year', None)
    week = self.request.query_params.get('week', None)
    name = self.request.query_params.get('name', None)

    if name and week and year is not None:

      prefetchCredits = Prefetch('user__credits', queryset=Credits.objects.filter(year=year, 
      week=week))

      prefetchMembership = Prefetch('membership_set', 
      queryset=Membership.objects.prefetch_related(prefetchCredits))

      group = Group.objects.filter(name__iexact=name).prefetch_related(prefetchMembership)

      return group
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work to use .annotate on the Credits fields and then use order_by. For some reason, all the Credits objects in de DB are used and not the filtered Prefetched objects with year and week. So Prefetch is ignored.

My question is how to order/sort as described above in python. I keep getting errors because of the nested querysets and the Membership model is many-to-many.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the desired result in the following way:

```
class GroupSet(generics.ListAPIView):
    lookup_field = 'name'
    serializer_class = GroupSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):

        year = self.request.query_params.get('year', None)
        week = self.request.query_params.get('week', None)
        name = self.request.query_params.get('name', None)

        if name and week and year is not None:

            weekStr = str(week)
            yearStr = str(year)
            yearweekStr = yearStr + '-W' + weekStr
            r = datetime.datetime.strptime(yearweekStr + '-7', "%G-W%V-%u").date()

            prefetchCredits = Prefetch('user__credits', queryset=Credits.objects.filter(year=year, week=week))

            prefetchMemberships = Prefetch('membership_set', queryset=Membership.objects.prefetch_related(prefetchCredits))

            sortedMemberships = sorted(prefetchMemberships.queryset, key=lambda e: (e.user.credits.all()[0].credits, e.user.credits.all()[0].game_count, e.user.credits.all()[0].last_game_credits),
                         reverse=True)

            group = Group.objects.filter(name__iexact=name)

            newGroup = [
                {
                    'name': group[0].name,
                    'id': group[0].id,
                    'membership_set': sortedMemberships

                }
            ]

            return newGroup
```

After the Memberships are retrieved with the Prefetched Credits the members are sorted. This creates a list so it cannot be used in prefetch_related when calling the Group object. Hence the newGroup object is composed of data from the group and storedMemberships variables.

If someone has a less devious solution I would love to hear it.